# Convert IEEE 754-floating point back to decimal in C language?

Tags: c, hex, ieee-754

Is there any code that allows me to convert 32-bit number in IEEE 754-floating point format back to decimal number? Preferably in C?

---

Sorry for my bad description.

Say I have `0x43ab9567` (this is in ieee754-floating point format), and I to convert to decimal.

`0x43ab9567` (ieee754-floating point ) ->`343.1672` (decimal)

Comment: Never heard of that format - where is it described?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It is ieee 754

Comment: Huh? what do you mean 'normal decimal'? Do you mean from a binary/hex string of an IEE-754 number to a decimal string?

Comment: You can store it in a 4-byte char array and then cast it to a `float *`.

Comment: This post is unclear.  How do you have `0x43ab9567`?  Is that a string, text, an array of bytes, etc?  Instead of discussing the number, post code that shows how you have `0x43ab9567`.

Comment: Your updated content is not anymore clearer. Do you want a string representation stored in `char[]`? In any case there are a lot of duplicates on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191203/convert-float-to-string-without-sprintf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302969/how-to-implement-char-ftoafloat-num-without-sprintf-library-function-i http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268725/how-can-i-convert-a-float-double-to-ascii-without-using-sprintf-or-ftoa-in-c

Answer (score 3):

Its is unclear whether you're looking for a string representation, mathematical transformation, or a tool to extract the components of a float:

To get a string representation, coerce to a double and call [*ftoa()*](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-floating-point-number-strin)?

```
float f = 3.14159;

printf("%s\n", ftoa((double) f)));
```

To extract the parts of the representation, coerce to a double, and then use [frexp()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_frexp.htm).

To manipulate in [mathematically](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), using bit-shifts and and-masks to extract the three components (sign, exponent offset by 127, and the mantissa):

```
raw = 0x43ab9567;                
sign = raw >> 31;                            // 0
mantissa = (raw & 0x7FFFFF) | 0x800000;      // 11244903
exp = ((raw >> 23) & 0xFF) - 127 - 23;       // -15
result = mantissa * pow(2.0, exp);           // 343.1672
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
union { uint32_t b; float f; } u;
u.b = 0x43ab9567;
printf("%g\n", u.f);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @TiesonT. sorry for the bad manners; I saw my post was edited, I hope to better reflect the expected style. However, I really think it provides an answer: the union is the mechanism to change between representations, and according to C standard §F.3, printf and the related functions "provide IEC 60559 binary-decimal conversions."

Comment: Yes, this method also does the math.